# Infering instead of where cluase

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to simplify a where clause so I don't have to list every column in the table.

An example would be like this:

## Select Drink_Names that only contain Gin, Rum, Vodka in them.

```
SELECT Drink_Name
FROM Answer
WHERE Gin IS NOT NULL 
AND Rum IS NOT NULL 
AND Vodka IS NOT NULL 
AND Lager IS NULL 
AND Cider IS NULL
AND Tequila IS NULL
AND Whiskey IS NULL
AND Baileys IS NULL
AND Cola IS NULL
```

## Flat Table Design:

```
Drink_Name      Baileys Cider   Cola    Gin    Lager    Rum   Tequila Vodka Whiskey
Mary Hinge      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       1    NULL    NULL       1
Ringsting       NULL       1       1    NULL    NULL    NULL       1    NULL       1
Stonehenge      NULL       1    NULL       1       1       1    NULL       1    NULL
Typhoon Lagoon  NULL    NULL    NULL       1    NULL       1    NULL       1    NULL
Wet and Wild       1    NULL       1    NULL    NULL    NULL       1       1    NULL
```

## Suggested Design

## Drink Table:

```
    Drink_NameID
    Drink_Name
```

## Ingredient Table:

```
    Drink_NameID
    Ingredient_Name
```

## Drink Table Data:

```
    Mary Hinge
    Ringsting
    Stonehenge
    Typhoon Lagoon
    Wet and Wild
```

## Ingredient Table Data:

```
    Baileys
    Cider
    Cola
    Gin
    Lager
    Rum
    Tequila
    Vodka
    Whiskey
```

Comment: You need to rethink the design of your table — probably using several tables.  Given the design you show, your WHERE clause is unavoidable.

Comment: Please edit your data into the question!  Given the design, you'll have to live with the consequences of your design, and one of those consequences is that the query you wrote is the way to answer the question you wish to answer.  Using NULL is not necessarily a good idea, either, but it can be made to work adequately.

Comment: Have a `drinks` table, with a `drinks_id`. Then a `drink_contents` table with (drink_id, name). Then `select distinct drinks_id from drink_contents where name="Gin" or name="Rum" or name="Vodka"` (or `name in ("Gin" "Rum" "Vodka")` if the list can be long. Etc.

Comment: Would that not make it a lot more heavily processed then, as you would be doing a text search over a Boolean flag ?

Comment: No boolean flag in my design. The ingredient Foo is in drink X if there's a row with drink_id == X and name == "Foo". It's not in the drink if there is no row like that. And, no, it won't be slow, that's what RDBMS are good at.

Comment: Also, if you ever come up with a new ingredient (say "Limocello"), you'd have to change your table design to allow for that. Which is pretty iffy. Different values of an entity belong in the table data, not in the table design itself.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: so for reporting purposes which is better flat table or RDBMS ?

Comment: it depends on your application, but there are many good reporting tools for RDMBS databases. You certainly shouldn't be driving your db design based on premature optimisation worries or premature performance worries. Especially if your use case is the actual one - how many different drinks ingredients, or even different drinks can there be? You're not even going to slightly test the scalability limits of any RDBMS.

Comment: But that is the purpose of the table for reporting so should the fore thought not be designed into the table? surely that's best practice?

Comment: Your table design is horrific. Listen to @Paul; he's giving good advice. Your design is extremely difficult to query, impossible to extend without immense work, and extremely inefficient (almost impossible to index properly, for instance). The fact that it's for reporting purposes does not mean you throw good design in the trash.

Comment: Reporting tools for RDBMS are designed expecting there to be multiple tables. They work just fine with multiple tables. Until you know you have a problem, you don't need to worry about reporting. Your current design is difficult to report on (try to write a query for "show me all drinks with less than three ingredients" for example)

Comment: @KenWhite Ken I wasn't be facetious, I was just trying to understand sorry if it came across that way. 

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It's not an answer, but it's too big for a comment)

You asked to simplify your where clause in order to select Drink_Names that only contain Gin, Rum, Vodka in them

In your current version your query will look like:

```
SELECT Drink_Name 
FROM Answer 
WHERE Gin IS NOT NULL  AND Rum IS NOT NULL AND Vodka IS NOT NULL;
```

You were told to make your structure better. OK, your structure will look something like this (I ommited foreign keys, ids etc):

```
create view good_structure as 
select drink_name, drink_type, amount from answer 
unpivot exclude nulls(
  amount for drink_type in (baileys as 'baileys', cider as 'cider', cola as 'cola', gin as 'gin', lager as 'lager', 
                            rum as 'rum', tequila as 'tequila', vodka as 'vodka', whiskey as 'whiskey')
);
```

With this good structure we are ready to simplify your query:

```
SELECT distinct Drink_Name 
FROM good_structure g
WHERE exists (select 1 from good_structure g2 where g2.drink_name = g.drink_name and g2.drink_type = 'Gin' and g2.amount > 0)
  AND exists (select 1 from good_structure g2 where g2.drink_name = g.drink_name and g2.drink_type = 'Rum' and g2.amount > 0)
  AND exists (select 1 from good_structure g2 where g2.drink_name = g.drink_name and g2.drink_type = 'Vodka' and g2.amount > 0);
```

Much simpler :)

So if your purpose is to simplify the query than your current is simple enough. If you want a good design than I suppose it's another question...

Here is some refactoring script which may help you to get the idea:

```
-- remove all
drop table drink_recipes;
drop table ingredients;
drop table drinks;

drop sequence drinks_seq;
drop sequence ingredients_seq;
drop sequence drink_recipes_seq;

-- create tables
create table DRINKS (drink_id number(10) primary key, drink_name varchar2(255));
create table INGREDIENTS (ingredient_id number(10) primary key, ingredient_name varchar2(255));
create table DRINK_RECIPES (
  recipe_id number(10) primary key, 
  drink_id number(10) references DRINKS(drink_id), 
  ingredient_id number(10) references INGREDIENTS(ingredient_id), 
  amount number(5)
);
-- recipe_id may be redundant

-- create sequences (if needed)
create sequence drinks_seq;
create sequence ingredients_seq;
create sequence drink_recipes_seq;


-- fill the data
insert into drinks
select drinks_seq.nextval, drink_name from (select distinct drink_name from answer);

insert into INGREDIENTS
with unpivoted as (
  select drink_name, drink_type, amount from answer 
  unpivot exclude nulls(
    amount for drink_type in (baileys as 'baileys', cider as 'cider', cola as 'cola', gin as 'gin', lager as 'lager', 
                              rum as 'rum', tequila as 'tequila', vodka as 'vodka', whiskey as 'whiskey')
  )
)
select ingredients_seq.nextval, drink_type from (
select distinct drink_type from unpivoted);


insert into DRINK_RECIPES
with unpivoted as (
  select drink_name, drink_type, amount from answer 
  unpivot exclude nulls(
    amount for drink_type in (baileys as 'baileys', cider as 'cider', cola as 'cola', gin as 'gin', lager as 'lager', 
                              rum as 'rum', tequila as 'tequila', vodka as 'vodka', whiskey as 'whiskey')
  )
),
help as (
  select d.drink_id, i.ingredient_id, u.amount 
   from unpivoted u join drinks d on u.drink_name = d.drink_name
                    join ingredients i on u.drink_type = i.ingredient_name
)
select drink_recipes_seq.nextval, drink_id, ingredient_id, amount from help;
```

Comment: I knew the answer would incorporate me changing the structure of my table but wanted to be sure I wasn't creating problems for myself further down the line, never used the unpivot before so I shall give a try, one thought though is would it not be better to use CTE instead of creating a view then?

Comment: @David You don't need UNPIVOT at all. Just create your structure and fill in with your data. Although you may use unpivot to simplify this process. I can update my answer to include some steps how to create your new tables

Comment: @David I've included a refactoring DDL if you want to make your structure better